# Unable to Archive Xcode Project: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ensembles

So I am trying to Archive my Xcode project to upload to the app store however I am getting the following error;

> PBXp Error
>
> error:
>   /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-aurgdfrsdgrsdgwzxglhhaw/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/APPNAME/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyBundle.bundle:
>   No such file or directory

I have tried;

- Deleting Derived Data
- Build and Run Bundle
- Changing Project/Build Settings "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to Yes
- Editing Bundle Schema and adding framework

Does anybody have any ideas why this is happening & how to resolve ?

**UPDATE**

The files are shown as missing when dragging and dropping the project into my project;

[image]

I am unable to run the project without the PBXp error until I run each target individually. Then the project runs fine.

However It is still an issue when archiving.

Comment: Are you using XConfig files for managing your xcodeproj ?

Comment: Is there a build phase to copy the bundle into your app?

Comment: @user3351949 Nope, I simply tagged and dropped following these instructions https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles

Comment: @DrewMcCormack not to sure what you mean sorry, I have removed the When dragging and dropping the `Ensembles iOS.xcodeproj` into my project the files are shown as missing, until I run the different targets individually. If I don't I get the error when running the project. After running the targets I can then run the project, however I now get the issue when archiving.

Comment: @DrewMcCormack I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably that the `Ensembles.bundle` is not being built in your Release build for archiving.

Add *Ensembles Resources iOS* as a dependency of your own app. That will ensure it builds before your app, including the Release build. You set that in the Build Phases tab of your app's target.